# Best way to get recent date rows? (this week/month)

Tags: sql, mysql

I wanna get rows in recent date, this week or month, etc. suppose the table has a field named: product_date.

Comment: Tell us more about your table structure. What type is the "product_date" field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the rows in the last month, you could use something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE product_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

Or for the last week:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE product_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK);
```

Answer (score 2):

For within the last seven days:

```
WHERE product_date BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -7 DAY) AND NOW()
```

For the last month:

```
WHERE product_date BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH) AND NOW()
```

Answer (score 0):

While mopoke's solution gets results from last 30 or 7 days, this gives you results for current month only:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE_FORMAT(product_date, '%c-%Y') = DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%c-%Y');
```

Or for current week:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE_FORMAT(product_date, '%u-%Y') = DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%u-%Y');
```

Comment: Using a function (in this case DATE_FORMAT) means that an index, if one existed on the `product_date` column, could not be used.

Comment: That is correct, but on smaller datasets that's an acceptable drawback if you *must* have the results for current week or month - at least I'm not aware of any other method.